# how to limit number of rows when paging=false?

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

My goal is to display only 10 first rows in datatable.

I use : `pageLength: 10`
This works fine when `paging = true`

However I don't want to display the pagination either: 
When I put `paging=false`, there is no pagination but ALL rows are shown.

Answer (score 2):

Set paging to true, pageLength to 10 then add this to your table definition

```
   initComplete: function () {
              $("#example_paginate").css("display", "none");
           }
```

where "example" is replace by the name of your table. It worked in my local environment.